# What is the purpose of the capacitor in this SMPS circuit?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, analysis

Can anyone tell me the purpose of the 2n2 100V capacitor and its function in the circuit?

[image: Schematic of 12 V, 5 A power supply]

Image source: [danyk.cz - 12V 5A switched power supply](https://danyk.cz/impulz3_en.html)

Comment: Welcome! Please inline the schematic and link to image source. Have you tried to simulate the circuit?

Comment: I suggest recreating the circuit in a simulator like LTspice. This may be a little more challenging than it sounds, but would be a great learning experience.

Answer (score 7):

Essentially this is already said by Rohat Kılıç but you may want to see it written in a less strictly formal way.

Without that capacitor it's possible that the circuit finds a stable balance where it does not oscillate. I mean the state where the MOSFET draws just that amount drain current that generates just the right Ib to transistor KC507 to pull the gate voltage of the MOSFET down just as much as is needed to maintain the MOSFET Id. The situation is dangerous. High continuous Vds and constant Id at the same time will very likely burn the MOSFET quickly.

The positive feedback through the 2n2 capacitor prevents any stable operating point. It makes the circuit an oscillator. The MOSFET turns fast on and fast off. The turn-off happens when there's maximum allowed current through the primary winding. The transistor senses the voltage over the current sense resistor. Turn-off produces the inductive kickback pulse (also known as flyback pulse in old days CRT TV-technology) which feeds a new portion charge to the 2200 uF output capacitor to be consumed. The oscillation keeps a pause as long as there's enough DC voltage in the output.

Remove or reduce the 2n2 cap  => no oscillation

Make the 2n2 cap bigger => difficulties in the startup because charging it may prevent high enough Vgs a while.  I'm sure 10x bigger capacitance is still allowed.

Answer (score 5):

It's there to accelerate the turn-on of the MOSFET (IRF840).

*I'm going to try to explain over the start up but still the same thing applies for steady state.*

When the power is first applied, the gate-source voltage of NMOS (IRF840) starts to increase from zero. As it turns on, its drain-source resistance decreases and this makes the no-dot-end of the primary winding (marked as **15** - probably number of turns)  more positive w.r.t. dot-ends *(it's actually making the dot-ends more negative w.r.t no-dot-ends)*. Same thing happens for auxiliary (or feedback) winding (marked with **3**) - look at the dots. This creates a positive feedback and accelerates the turn-on of the MOSFET by passing current through 2n2, to charge up the gate-source capacitor quicker.

I'm not going to explain the rest of the operation as it's out of the question's scope.

Comment: what happens if I change the value or remove the cap ? kindly explain

Comment: If that was your question, you should have asked it in the question.  This is not a discussion board.